# How to find the font

Tags: fonts

I tried to identify the font below with this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en

I cannot find ff18 font as real font, so is there a way to actually find it ?

[image]

Comment: The site where you found it? If they are able to make your browser display it, they have it.

Answer (score 1):

There exist Chrome extensions that will tell the font that is used on any text that
you see in the browser.

Here are some such extensions:

- [WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en)
- [Fontface Ninja](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fontface-ninja/eljapbgkmlngdpckoiiibecpemleclhh?hl=en)
- [Font Finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-finder/bhiichidigehdgphoambhjbekalahgha?hl=en)

The following tutorial explains how to use WhatFont:
[How to Identify Any Font on Any Web Page the Easy Way](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/identify-font-web-page/).

[image]